# Символ "рубль" для всех устройств

Tags: html, css

Использую такой знак `₽` на сайте, но на старых мобильных устройствах он отображается так `□`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше всего его оптимизировать под разные мобильные устройства?

Comment: А на новых компьютерах просто квадрат! 8-О

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/

Comment: @Эникейщик Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Dmitry OnGamer  Спасибо. Это самый оптимальный вариант?

Comment: А что непонятного-то? Вместо символа рубль все три браузера мне показывают квадрат.

Comment: @Эникейщик Специально для вас прикрепил картинку.

Comment: @Дмитрий между вставкой изображения и подключением дополнительного шрифта я выбираю шрифт, т.к. можно изменять размер, цвет и т.д.

Comment: Да я знаю, что там должно быть :) У меня на обоих местах квадраты, только первый больше размеров и в фаерфоксе в нем еще что-то написано. Я к тому, что проблемы могут быть не только со старыми мобильными устройствами.

Comment: @Dmitry OnGamer  Воспользуюсь ваши вариантом. Спасибо

Comment: @Эникейщик На чем проблему увидел - о том и говорю. Думаю суть одна.

Comment: Использовать шрифт с этим символом

Comment: Идеальный вариант - отказаться от мерзкого знака и использовать нормальное и православное обозначение `руб.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
p{
    font-family: 'PT Sans', serif;    
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:regular,italic,bold,bolditalic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<p>&#8381;</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте SVG.

```css
svg{
 width: 12px
}
```

```html
<p>

 <span>Самый дешевый утюг стоит</span>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 440 440"><path d="M232.522 242.428c63.913 0 115.91-54.382 115.91-121.227C348.432 54.37 296.435 0 232.522 0H120.568v282.428h-29v30h29V440h30V312.428h101.955v-30H150.568v-40h81.954zM150.568 30h81.955c47.371 0 85.91 40.912 85.91 91.201 0 50.303-38.539 91.227-85.91 91.227h-81.955V30z"/></svg><span>999.</span>


</p>
```

При желании SVG можно подключить в ваш иконочный шрифт.